Why does it take over a minute for PS to change directory
$directoryPath = "C:\Logs"
$daysOld = 30
$cutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysOld)

[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($directoryPath, "*", [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $file = $_
        $fileInfo = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $file
        if ($fileInfo.LastWriteTime -lt $cutoffDate) {
            $fileInfo.Delete()
            Write-Output "Deleted: $file" (Get-Date)
        }
    }

In output can see that it takes ages between directories, over a minute, thoughts ?

How many files there are? Subdirectories?

Which PowerShell and .Net version? Besides: why using .Net classes instead of the native PowerShell commands Get-ChildItem and Get-Item?

Figured .net should be faster ( its literally thousands of files to delete weekly, 4 sub-directories)
PS v5.1 .net 4.8

"its literally thousands of files" that is your Windows issue. Anyways, I bet you will get more performance if you use the latest PowerShell (and .net) version. Besides, I suspect that there isn't any performance advantage here where you wrap cmdlets as New-Object which has some performance disadvantages (see: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/11491).

A native PowerShell (Pipeline) command for this would be: Get-ChildItem $directoryPath -File -Recurse | Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt $cutoffDate | Remove-Item -WhatIf -Verbose

GetFiles needs to collect everything before outputting, that's your main issue. You need to use EnumerateFiles instead:

The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows:

When you use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of FileInfo objects before the whole collection is returned.

When you use GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of FileInfo objects to be returned before you can access the array.


Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.

You should also avoid New-Object and ForEach-Object if you're looking for performance.
In summary:
$dirInfo = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new('C:\Logs')
$daysOld = 30
$cutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysOld)

foreach ($file in $dirInfo.EnumerateFiles('*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)) {
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $cutoffDate) {
        $file.Delete()
        Write-Output "Deleted: $($file.FullName)" (Get-Date)
    }
}

